# How to test for unset parameter in rebol / red within a function?

Tags: rebol, red

When I call f without parameter, I got the error Script Error: if does not allow unset! for its then-blk argument why ?

```
f: func['p [string! unset!]][
     if unset? 'p print "unset"
]
```

Comment: Note that UNSET! as a "value" (which can be appended to blocks) is problematic.  This may be of interest: ["Why (or why not) have UNSET! in Rebol-like Languages"](https://forum.rebol.info/t/why-or-why-not-have-unset-in-rebol-like-languages/113)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'p` evaluates to the word `p`. In order to test the type of the value referred by `p`, you need to use `:p` and provide a proper body block for `if`:

```
f: func ['p [string! unset!]][
    if unset? :p [print "unset"]
]

>> f "123"
== none
>> f
unset
```